# Webservice redirected with HTTP 302 to AccessDenied.aspx

Tags: 2013, access-denied

I have running custom webservices running on my **SharePoint 2013** machine for several years, without any issues. (Deployed as FarmSolution). There was no deployment of the FarmSolution in the last three month on this Farm.

This morning (as early christmas present?!) my **REST service request**

https://mypage.domain.intern/_layouts/15/xxx.xxx/myApp/Overviews/Overview.aspx/GetGridData

it returns an HTTP 302 and is redirected to

https://mypage.domain.intern/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx

for unknown reasons.

I checked access on https://mypage.domain.intern/_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx

The Group setting for "Read" has as members "Domain Users" and I added also "Everyone" to ensure that everyone should be able to use it, but this didn't help, the redirection always comes.

I use the Farm account with the URL and Site Collection Admin Accounts, but always get redirected to "AccessDenied".

In ULS Viewer I get for the request only this information:

```
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\my_farm_account, ClaimsCount=54

SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page: https://mypage.domain.intern/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx
```

I checked the Windows Update History, there was no new installation since 3 weeks.

The farm has 4 servers (2 front-end, 2 back-end), and all make the same redirect to "AccessDenied.aspx"

I tried also grant access on

https://mypage.domain.intern/Access%20Requests/pendingreq.aspx

and approve the requests, giving the user "Full Control"

Do you have any idea, what I can do or have to check?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this case was a little bit weird.

I reconfigured the Claim Based Authentication for the WebApps from Kerberos to NTLM and then back to Kerberos.

Now everything works well again. It reconfigurated the IIS Authentication Rules to enable only "Windows Authentication" (which is ok), now everything works fine again.

Something seems to have changed this IIS settings (which only should manged by SharePoint itself), so that other Authentication Solutions where active.